# Defining the presehaf Hom(-,U) as a sheaf

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, hom-functor

I was reading the second chapter of *Sheaves in geometry and logic* by Mac Lane and there he says the following,

> On a space X, each open set U determines a presheaf Hom(-,U) defined, for each open set V, by
> Hom(V,U)=1 if $V \subset U$ or $Hom(V,U)= \emptyset$ otherwise.

They say that this sheaf is clearly a sheaf and I was wondering, in order to prove the two sheaf axioms, how I would build the respective equalizer. Just a note, my definition of a sheaf (also given by this book) is the following:

> A sheaf of sets F on a topological space X is a functor $F:\mathscr{O}(X)^{op} \mapsto Sets$ such that each open covering $U=\cup_iU_i$, $i\in I$ of an open set U of X yields an equalizer diagram
> [image]

I saw some people here use something as the sheaf Hom (like here: prove-that-sheaf-hom-is-a-sheaf) and i was wondering if it was the same thing that I am trying to build.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sheaf and the sheaf mentioned in the linked question are two different objects.

Your sheaf is the representable presheaf corresponding to the open $U$, meaning that it maps an object $V$ to the set of morphisms $V\rightarrow U$, which is a one-point set if $V\subseteq U$ and the empty set otherwise.

In the linked question, they are defining the sheaf of morphisms $\mathcal F\rightarrow\mathcal G$ between *two sheaves* $\mathcal F,\mathcal G$. This sheaf has the property that global sections are exactly the set of morphisms of sheaves $\mathcal F\rightarrow\mathcal G$ (i.e. natural transformations between functor $\mathscr O(X)^{op}\rightarrow\mathcal Set$). On the other hand, the global sections of $\text{Hom}(-,U)$ are empty if $U\neq X$ and are a one-point set if $U=X$.

You can see the difference also in the inputs. Your sheaf takes as input a single open set $U$ and constructs a sheaf out of it. In the linked question, they take as input two sheaves $\mathcal F,\mathcal G$.

Comment: thank you, I understood perfectly!